# Date filter with case condition SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have 2 tables where one holds history of a record as follows

```
CREATE TABLE Student
(
    StudentId INT,
    StudentName NVARCHAR(200)
)

CREATE TABLE StudentHist
(
    StudentHistId INT,
    BranchId INT,
    StudentId INT,
    ExitDate DATE
)

INSERT INTO Student 
VALUES (1, 'ABC'), (2, 'PQR')

INSERT INTO StudentHist 
VALUES (1, 1, 1, null), (2, 2, 1, '2016-01-01'),
       (3, 2, 2, '2017-01-01')

SELECT S.StudentName
FROM Student S 
INNER JOIN StudentHist SH ON S.StudentId = SH.StudentId
                          AND (SH.ExitDate IS NULL OR SH.ExitDate >= getdate())
                          AND SH.BranchId = 2
```

Currently I have a query which is giving the records where exit date is null, what I need is a switch condition where it will check the date is null and execute current code if not get the latest by histid and get the date

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1036cec8a82566534665c89f7279ebcb

Comment: Please provide a sample of what your results should look like.

Comment: If I filter with branch2 I am not getting data where it should get the result

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question? As per your condition, it won't return any data.

Comment: on filter of branch2 your date condition is not allowing data in current raw data.

Comment: Yeah but what I need is irrespective of any I need the data with that condition, I need like when date is null apply the current filer, else another